# Is there any method like tableViewWillEndDisplayingCell in iOS for UITableViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I would like to fade cell in table view in my iPhone application before it disappears. When it is about to appear I use

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
   willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell
 forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
```

to change alpha from zero to 1 with 0.3 sec animation.

I would like to to the same but from 1 to zero when it is about to disappear. Is it any method similar to the one above or how else can I do that?

I don't want to use standard iOS `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` because I don't want any other transitions while reloading table.

**EDIT:**
I am reloading content of the table view. Let say that I have a button which I click and it reloads data in my table. That is when I want to fade out existing cells and fade in new ones.

The controller I am using is a basic `UIViewController` implementing `UITableViewDataSource` `UITableViewDelegate` `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocols.

Comment: you can try viewDidDisappear

Comment: @T_77 That's a `UIViewController` method, not anything that can be used for a single cell (a `UIView`).

Comment: The author mentioned the uitableview ,but not the uitableviewcontroller. So I assumed the author has the tableview in the uiviewcontroller

Comment: Just to clarify--if a cell's about to disappear, do you mean that it's about to be removed? Or do you want to fade each cell when the *whole table* is about to disappear?

Comment: I really suggest using collection view for that which allows you to do such craze via layout attributes.

Comment: @NRitH I want each cell to fade when this cell is about to disappear (be removed) - but the tableview still exists. The thing is that after clicking on one button I reload data in table view so I want to reload cells with that animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

Just before calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` I am animating all visible cells to fade out. I get all visible cells and iterate over them by

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows])
{
    // here I animate cells to fade out
}
```

(thanks @AlexKoren for showing me the way to iterate over visible cells).

Because I was using `[self.tableView reloadData]` without any additional iOS built-in animation the cells were just disappearing. So now they are fading first and then my new cells are fading in with animation defined in

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
   willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell
 forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
```

**Important**: I am reloading table view after animation is finished. If I called `[self.tableView reloadData]` just after iterating over cells it would reload table before animation was displayed. Because I know how long it takes to finish animation I use

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                {
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });
```

with `delay` calculated before.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but should work:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //loop through visible indexPaths
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
        //get each cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //get its location
        CGRect rectInTableView = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //set its alpha based on whether or not its going off the screen at the top.
        cell.alpha = 1 + rectInTableView.origin.y / rectInTableView.size.height;
    }

}
```

Comment: That would work but I want all visible cells to fade out when tableview content is reload. That would only fade them when they are about to disappear because of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: That will be call after it's completely gone from UITableView